# Roles based authorization using JWT token with Roles without verifying the token

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am getting a JWT token to the java back-end from the UI which contains "roles" in it. I am trying to implement role based authorization(secure the Rest APIs) using spring security using that token. The problem is that i  do not have the JWT Signing Key. I just want to decode(without verifying the token) and implement authorization using the roles in the JWT. How can i do that? Any articles/websites as to how to achieve this would be helpful. I tried decoding the token without signing key using JJWT(JsonWebToken), but always the Claims value is Null.

```
String token = "ey.....";
Claims claims;
try {
    claims = Jwts.parser()
             .parseClaimsJws(token)
             .getBody();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Check with other tools like [jwt.io's debugger](https://jwt.io/). If that shows no claims either, there probably aren't any and you need to fix how the token is issued. If that shows claims, add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: accepting tokens without checking signage means that anyone can forge a token, and its basically no security at all. You might as well just disable all security and remove spring security, than having tokens that you are not verifying.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not me accepting a token’s contents without validating it but here goes.

The token has three bits separated by a full stop (.).

Split it with `String.split”.”);`

Each section is base64 encoded. Decode the middle bit (AFAICR) with `new String(Base64.decoder.decode(middleBit.getBytes()))`

This will be a bit of JSON with the claims.

Note that, for validating/unpacking a JWT the signing key is the **public ke**y of the signer.